# Java String .isBlank() works in Eclipse/Powershell but not in Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, java-runtime-compiler

I have a question.
I have written a program that sends me an SMS as soon as something specific does not appear in a log.
However, it is about this method:

```
private static void sendWarningSMS() {
        try {
            String computerName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
            URL url = new URL("https://gatewayapi.com/rest/mtsms");
            log("sendWarningSMS","we've reached sendWarningSMS. Right before if statement");
            log("sendWarningSMS","Value of mobileNumberFromConfigFile: "+mobileNumberFromConfigFile);
            if(mobileNumberFromConfigFile != null && !mobileNumberFromConfigFile.isBlank()) {
                HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                os.writeBytes(
                        "token=*****"
                                + "&sender=" + URLEncoder.encode("SC Warning", "UTF-8")
                                + "&message=" + URLEncoder.encode("Censored " +computerName + " Censored", "UTF-8")
                                + "&recipients.0.msisdn=" + mobileNumberFromConfigFile
                        );
                os.close();
            
                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                log("SMS","SMS Warnung wurde an " + mobileNumberFromConfigFile + " gesendet. Antwort von GatewayAPI:" + responseCode);              
                }else {
                    log("ERROR","SMS konnte nicht gesendet werden. Es wurde keine Telefonnummer im Config File erfasst.");
                }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            log("SMS","Fehler in der sendWarningSMS Methode"+e);
        } catch(IOException e1) {
            log("SMS","Fehler in der sendWarningSMS Methode"+e1);
        }
        log("sendWarningSMS","end of sendWarningSMS method.");
    }
```

Why is here

```
if(mobileNumberFromConfigFile != null && !mobileNumberFromConfigFile.isBlank())
```

in Eclipse and Powershell false and is executed, but in an exported JAR true and is not executed? If I remove

```
&& mobileNumberFromConfigFile.isBlank()
```

it also works in the JAR.

The config file is an .ini file and is read by Java with properties. The config file looks like this:

```
numberToSend=12345678
name=
location=
```

It is not a big problem, but I am interested in the why.

Many thanks for your help.
Greetings,

I have logged everything and everywhere.
The number is taken correctly from the config file.
We also get into the method up to the if block, which is no longer executed. The else block is also not executed and therefore not logged.

Log when application is running in Eclipse/Powershell with && !.isBlank:

```
[Sat Jan 13 02:38:37 CET 2024] Client: Erfolgreich zum Server verbunden.
[Sat Jan 13 02:38:37 CET 2024] sendWarningSMS: weve reached sendWarningSMS. Right before if statement
[Sat Jan 13 02:38:37 CET 2024] sendWarningSMS: Value of mobileNumberFromConfigFile: 12341234565
[Sat Jan 13 02:38:38 CET 2024] SMS: SMS Warnung wurde an 12341234565 gesendet. Antwort von GatewayAPI:200
[Sat Jan 13 02:38:38 CET 2024] sendWarningSMS: end of sendWarningSMS method.
```

Log when application is startet from exportet JAR with && !.isBlank:

```
[Sat Jan 13 02:45:43 CET 2024] Client: Erfolgreich zum Server verbunden.
[Sat Jan 13 02:45:43 CET 2024] sendWarningSMS: weve reached sendWarningSMS. Right before if statement
[Sat Jan 13 02:45:43 CET 2024] sendWarningSMS: Value of mobileNumberFromConfigFile: 12341234565
```

Log when application is startet from Eclipse **without** && !.isBlank:

```
[Sat Jan 13 02:50:37 CET 2024] Client: Erfolgreich zum Server verbunden.
[Sat Jan 13 02:50:37 CET 2024] sendWarningSMS: weve reached sendWarningSMS. Right before if statement
[Sat Jan 13 02:50:37 CET 2024] sendWarningSMS: Value of mobileNumberFromConfigFile: 12341234565
[Sat Jan 13 02:50:37 CET 2024] SMS: SMS Warnung wurde an 12341234565 gesendet. Antwort von GatewayAPI:200
[Sat Jan 13 02:50:37 CET 2024] sendWarningSMS: end of sendWarningSMS method.
```

Log when application is startet from exportet JAR **without** && !.isBlank:

```
[Sat Jan 13 02:52:29 CET 2024] Client: Erfolgreich zum Server verbunden.
[Sat Jan 13 02:52:29 CET 2024] sendWarningSMS: weve reached sendWarningSMS. Right before if statement
[Sat Jan 13 02:52:29 CET 2024] sendWarningSMS: Value of mobileNumberFromConfigFile: 12341234565
[Sat Jan 13 02:52:29 CET 2024] SMS: SMS Warnung wurde an 12341234565 gesendet. Antwort von GatewayAPI:200
[Sat Jan 13 02:52:29 CET 2024] sendWarningSMS: end of sendWarningSMS method.
```

Comment: " in Eclipse and Powershell" what do you mean by PowerShell? Please provide a minimum example for reproduction with the actual values. Probably you should use a debugger first to understand the actual values involved.

Comment: @aled
Thanks for you response.
With Powershell i mean to start the exported JAR from Powershell to check if there's any Exceptions. But there are no Exceptions it just works how it should.

Comment: It's not java. It's you. That's 99.9999% the right assumption. The way you run it affects which config file is read (or, whether it finds a config file in the first place) and you wrote your own code such that it behaves differently then. Rest assured that `isBlank()` does not have an `if (userDoubleClickedJar) doNotWorkLikeTheSpecSays()` in it.

Comment: Also notice you have an inconsistency.  In the code the second condition is negated (`!`) while in your explanation it is not.  Which is it?

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for you hint. 
in the if statement the ! is used.

Comment: @rzwitserloot
Thanks for you answer. 
The correct config file is read because I use an absolute path to the file. If the config is not found, one is automatically created with all key values empty. If the Key Value numberToSend is empty, the warning is written to the log. I also log every exception and or cases of else. However, neither else nor an exception is triggered.

Comment: _"I have logged everything and everywhere"_ -- SHOW us, don't just tell us, for both the working and "non-working" cases.

Comment: The code you pasted is irrelevant. Where did you _create_ the string that variable `mobileNumberFromConfigFile` is pointing at? You say it's definitely the same file - doubtful. Or, the code that reads it ends up using a different character encoding depending on how you run it. "isBlank() does not work" which is what you have now, is not an answerable question.

Comment: If neither of the if or else parts is executing and the end of method log entry is not generated you must be getting a Exception which you are not catching - try adding a `catch` for `Throwable` and see what the exception is.

Comment: *The config file is an .ini file and is read by Java with properties* Then that's a resource and should be read as one such that it works the same whether or not packaged as a jar

Comment: The false condition in your `if` block is also an exception, not an acceptable code branch, so should be handled as such